What does the left_block_options array represent in the fill_decode_neighbors function of FFmpeg？
I am studying the source code of FFmpeg, specifically the fill_decode_neighbors function. I am trying to understand how the decoding process works, especially the usage of the left_block_options array.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
static const uint8_t left_block_options[4][32] = {
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 8, 11, 3 + 0 * 4, 3 + 1 * 4, 3 + 2 * 4, 3 + 3 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 1 + 8 * 4, 1 + 5 * 4, 1 + 9 * 4 },
        { 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 11, 8, 11, 3 + 2 * 4, 3 + 2 * 4, 3 + 3 * 4, 3 + 3 * 4, 1 + 5 * 4, 1 + 9 * 4, 1 + 5 * 4, 1 + 9 * 4 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 7, 10, 7, 10, 3 + 0 * 4, 3 + 0 * 4, 3 + 1 * 4, 3 + 1 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 1 + 8 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 1 + 8 * 4 },
        { 0, 2, 0, 2, 7, 10, 7, 10, 3 + 0 * 4, 3 + 2 * 4, 3 + 0 * 4, 3 + 2 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 1 + 8 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 1 + 8 * 4 }
    };

While I understand that this array plays a role in determining neighboring blocks for decoding, I am unclear about:
The specific meaning of the array values.
How this array interacts with the decoding process, especially in relation to intra-prediction or block positioning.
Instead of a detailed explanation, I would greatly appreciate:
Any keywords I can look up to understand this topic better (e.g., terms from the H.264 standard or FFmpeg documentation).
Links to related documentation, articles, or sections in the H.264 specification.
Suggestions on where I might find similar examples or detailed discussions about intra-block neighbor handling in FFmpeg.
Thank you for any resources or pointers you can provide!
